# eclipse CDT esp-idf build but don't flash

Tags: eclipse, launch, esp-idf

Windows10 eclipse esp-idf latest version 2021-03

---

With the command line  idf.py I can build and flash the esp-idf\examples\get-started\blink programme which run on a ESP32.

In eclipse, the buils works but the run command display in console

```
Usage: C:\Users\peter\esp-idf\tools\idf.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND1 [ARGS]...
                                           [COMMAND2 [ARGS]...]...

  ESP-IDF CLI build management tool. For commands that are not known to
  idf.py an attempt to execute it as a build system target will be made.
....  bla bla ...
```

Can anybody tells me what is wrong ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the eclipse/esp-idf launch bar.
The ESP target for esp32 is defined with a Serial Port COM3.
But that info is not used.

If one redefine a new ESP Target with the same serial port under a different name, then the run command will work!

See hereafter for the people interested in the details

cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\peter\esp-idf\components\esptool_py && C:\Users\peter.espressif\tools\cmake\3.16.4\bin\cmake.exe -D IDF_PATH="C:/Users/peter/esp-idf" -D ESPTOOLPY="C:\Users\peter.espressif\python_env\idf4.2_py3.8_env\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/peter/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py --chip esp32" -D ESPTOOL_ARGS="--before=default_reset --after=hard_reset write_flash @flash_args" -D WORKING_DIRECTORY="C:/Users/peter/eclipse-workspace/blink/build" -P C:/Users/peter/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/run_esptool.cmake"
esptool.py --chip esp32 -p COM3 -b 460800 --before=default_reset --after=hard_reset write_flash --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 40m --flash_size 2MB 0x8000 partition_table/partition-table.bin 0x1000 bootloader/bootloader.bin 0x10000 blink.bin
esptool.py v3.0